# call_usermodehelper / call_usermodehelperpipe usage

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I've followed this great document on invoking user apps from the kernel: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-user-space-apps/index.html

But I'm now interested in how to get the output from the apps that have been run. I tried passing in redirection operators to write the output to a file.. Eg:

```
char *argv[] = { "/usr/bin/ls", ">>", "/tmp/list", NULL};
call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);
```

No such luck. I came across `call_usermodehelperpipe` and wondered if that would be what I'm after, but I haven't been able to grasp how to use it or find any documents like the above one on it.

Thanks in advance for suggestions / help!

Answer (score 4):

`>>` is not an argument for `ls`, it is something from the shell. It can be parsed using`/bin/sh -c "ls >> /tmp/list"` (in shell). In C, this is:

```
char *argv[] = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "/bin/ls >> /tmp/list", NULL};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the usermodehelper code to do this, as it only supports running a process with `stdin` connected to a pipe.

You could duplicate its functionality, changing [`____call_usermodehelper`](http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/kernel/kmod.c?v=2.6.30#L136) to override `stdout` in addition to `stdin`.