# how to dump call stack in syscall(android kernel) ？

Tags: android, kernel, system-calls

I want to know who called *sys_reboot* when the phone(android) reboot unexpectly.

Is there a way to dump the call stack in **syscall**(android kernel)?

Comment: Note that a kernel call stack from `syscall` will be just one level deep ... given that it's the first way into the kernel. Are you sure you want the _kernel_ call stack at this time, or rather the _userland_ one ?

Comment: No, what I actually want is the **user space stack**. So I do not think 'dump_stack()' or 'panic()' can work

Comment: You'd need to stop the process / thread, `send_sig_info(SIGSTOP, SEND_SIG_FORCED, current)`, then spawn a _userspace helper_ (`gdb` or the `pstack` script, or a busybox-builtin) to get you the stacktrace, then continue the process.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want it a *kernel* call trace, you can get that via [`dump_stack()`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=lib/dump_stack.c). [`panic()`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=kernel/panic.c;hb=HEAD) calls that, amongst other things. The `BUG()` / `BUG_ON()` [wrappers](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=include/asm-generic/bug.h) give it a more descriptive message and an optional conditional test.

A *userland stacktrace*, particularly a symbolic one, though, cannot reliably be obtained from within the kernel directly. It's possible to copy the stack memory into kernel space and log the contents, or even heuristically walk `SP`/`FP` linkage if framepointers aren't optimized out, but to resolve symbols, it'd need to access and parse ELF information. I'm unsure anyone has done that as pure kernel-side implementation; an easier solution there would be to stop the program from your syscall hook, spawn a userspace debugger attaching to it, extracting a stacktrace, continuing the program when done.

See this SO posting, [call_usermodehelper / call_usermodehelperpipe usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143105/call-usermodehelper-call-usermodehelperpipe-usage) for how to do this.

See also this SO posting: [How to print the userspace stack trace in linux kernelspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199130/how-to-print-the-userspace-stack-trace-in-linux-kernelspace) for another reference to the same question.